# Should I put vector images in assets or drawables? I have thousand vectors in my app

Tags: android

If I put vector images in drawable folder, can I sub folder them in drawables because I have a lot of vectors and managing is a bit hard.

Comment: res/drawable will be best option

Comment: you can make a folder for each group like res/subFolder and res/raw. put them under this folder, they will be accessible for your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets folder is a general-purpose location for storing arbitrary files, including images, videos, audio, and more.

In your case, since you mentioned having thousands of vector images, placing them in the res/drawable folder would generally be the recommended approach. This ensures that Android's resource management system handles different screen densities and scaling for you. If the images have specific loading or management requirements, you can always consider custom loading logic while still keeping them in the res/drawable folder for proper resource handling.

Comment: What a about creating folders in drawables in order to sub folder those vectors, because it would be tidier if I could do that and easier to mange vectors.

Comment: You can`t as per the rules. Alternatively, you can use Descriptive Naming Convention that  can easy to manage

Comment: Let me know if that works for you